# Controller extn test class is failing with error : this ID value isn't valid for the user

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

When i run the test class for the below controller extn it is failing with the error

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: : [RecordTypeId]"

I checked the record type access and provided the access to all the opportunity record types to all the users, even after doing this also it failing.
please find the code for apex class and test class.

**Extension**

```
public class OpptyExtn {
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
    public OpptyExtn(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        opp = new Opportunity();
        string RecorftypeId =      ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType'); 
        opp.RecordTypeId=RecorftypeId;
    }

    public pagereference save(){
        pagereference p;
        insert opp;

        p= new pagereference('/'+opp.id);
        p.setredirect(true);
        return p;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest(seeAllData = true)
public class testOpptyExtn  {

    public static testMethod void testMyOpptyExtn() {
        opportunity opp = new opportunity();
        opp.name='test oppty';
        opp.StageName='Closed Won';
        opp.CloseDate=system.ToDay();
        //insert opp;
        OpptyExtn  con = new OpptyExtn (new ApexPages.StandardController(opp));
        con.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what you're getting for `RecorftypeId` and whether that's a valid Opportunity record type?

Comment: Do you have a *good reason* why you are using `SeeAllData`? You should avoid it at all costs.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you are reading record type ID from the URL parameter. But in your test method you are not setting the URL parameter. Please set it in the standard controller instance in your test class and check it

Comment: Thanks for Your reply George. I modified the test class as follows. but even after doing this also getting the same error. Any idea. my modified code is        public class OpptyExtn {
    
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
public OpptyExtn(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    opp = new Opportunity();
 string RecorftypeId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType'); 
 opp.RecordTypeId=RecorftypeId;
 }

public pagereference save(){
pagereference p;
upsert opp;
//if(!test.isRunningTest()){
 p= new pagereference('/'+opp.id);

p.setredirect(true);
return p;
}
}

Comment: Please print the record type ID in debug log and make sure that you are getting the record type ID in testclass. Also ensure that the current user ha access to the record type which you are passing into the standard Controller parameter

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that you are getting an invalid `RecordTypeId` from your parameters. You should try something like the following:

```
public class MyExtension
{
    public static final String RECORDTYPE_PARAM = 'RecordType';
    public Opportunity opportunity { get; private set; }
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        opportunity = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
        String recordType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(RECORDTYPE_PARAM);
        List<RecordType> candidates = [
            SELECT Id FROM RecordType
            WHERE DeveloperName = :recordType
            AND SObjectType = 'Opportunity'
            LIMIT 1
        ];
        if (!candidates.isEmpty()) opportunity.RecordTypeId = candidates[0].Id;
    }
}
```

In the above, you can replace `DeveloperName` with `Name`. It does not seem based on the error message like you are passing an `Id`.

When overwriting `save`, best practice is more along the lines of:

```
public PageReference save()
{
    try
    {
        insert opportunity;
    }
    catch (DmlException dmx)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(dmx);
        return null;
    }
    return new ApexPages.StandardController(opportunity).view();
}
```